# Laravel 5.3 update campo JSON MySql - #3143 - Invalid JSON path expression

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5.3

Query gerada pelo laravel:

```
update `informations` set `parameters` = json_set(`parameters`, "$.'Campo teste'.type", 'string'), `parameters` = json_set(`parameters`, "$.'Campo teste'.value", 'Novo valor') where `parameters`->'$."Identificação do campo"."type"' = 'string' and `parameters`->'$."Identificação do campo"."value"' = 'D25L'
```

Sintaxe laravel:

```
DB::table("informations")->where($data['where'])->update($data['update']);
```

O MySql me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
#3143 - Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 7.
```

Código array $data:

```
{
   "update": {
      "parameters->'Campo teste'->type": "string",
      "parameters->'Campo teste'->value": "Novo valor"
   },
   "where": {
      "parameters->Identificação do campo->type": "string",
      "parameters->Identificação do campo->value": "D25L"
   }
}
```

**Obs:**

Se eu faço uma simples *query* usando somente o trecho do `where` ele encontra os registos, acredito que o problema esteja no JSON_SET
 mesmo

Comment: Talvez isto ajude: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: posta o codigo do array `$data`

Comment: @13dev Postei ;)

Comment: @Miguel sim, montei o array na mesma estrutura que ele, a única diferença é que no meu uso espaço ao invés de underline onde em outros lugares tem se comportado muito bem inclusive no `where`

Comment: ta a causar este erro porque o laravel ao gerar o(s) parâmetro(s) `"$.'Campo teste'.type"` devia ser `'$."Campo teste".type'` aspas simples no final

Comment: @13dev sim, eu pensei a mesma coisa, os tipos de aspas invertida, será que pode ser considerado um bug deles? O mais estranho é que acontece só no update, no where funciona normalmente

Comment: possível, o melhor que tens a fazer é usar metodo `DB::raw()`

Comment: @13dev consegui corrigir fazendo uma alteração básica no Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz uma alteração no arquivo do laravel `MySqlGrammar.php` *localizado em:*

`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars`

**Linha** `155` **Método** `compileJsonUpdateColumn`

de:

```
$accessor = '"$.'.implode('.', $path).'"';
```

para

```
$accessor = "'$.".implode('.', $path)."'";
```

E no meu array no update adicionei aspas duplas:

```
    "update": {
      "parameters->\"Campo teste\"->type": "string",
      "parameters->\"Campo teste\"->value": "Novo valor"
   }
```